# Finding an angle after some projections

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

[image]

I want to find the function $g(X)=a(X)+b(X)$.

Suppose that $\alpha$ is a solution to $\tan\theta x=\tan\phi(x-X)$[*], then I know that $a=\alpha\tan\theta$, $c=\alpha-X$, and $b=\sqrt{f^2(x')-c^2}$. I then get that $g(X)=\alpha\tan\theta+\sqrt{f^2(x')-(\alpha-X)^2}$.

For a given $X$, $x'=\sqrt{\alpha^2+(\alpha\tan\theta)^2}=\sqrt{\alpha^2(1+\tan^2\theta)}=|\alpha\sec\theta|$.

To simplify a bit, I can recursively define $\alpha=X+f(x')\sin\theta$, which leads me to $g(X)=\alpha\tan\theta+|f(x')\cos\theta|$.

If I substitute with the value of $x'$, I get $g(X)=\alpha\tan\theta+|f(|\alpha\sec\theta|)\cos\theta|$.

But in order to define $\alpha$ without recursion, I need to find $\phi$.

$$\alpha=\frac{\tan\phi}{\tan\phi-\tan\theta}X,\,[*]$$

Any ideas? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Isn't $φ = π - θ$?

Comment: Your diagram is totally unclear to me. What is $\varphi$?

Comment: @TobyMak the yellow angle.

Comment: And is the vertical line (not the $y$-axis) perpendicular to the $x$-axis?

Comment: @TobyMak yes, the big one touching the curve.

Comment: What is the red curve? Is it a parabola or an ellipse?

Comment: @TobyMak an ellipse

Comment: I am trying to find the coordinate on the $x$-axis corresponding to the original coordinate before the rotation.

Comment: if $\alpha$ is a solution of $\tan\theta x-\tan?(x-X)$, then $f(X)$ corresponds to $y_\text{ellipse}(\sqrt{\alpha^2+(\tan\theta\alpha)^2})$

Comment: Suppose your red curve were higher up, so the angled perpendicular would be longer, which would push the vertical line, and therefore the vertex where it intersects the $x$-axis, to the left. This changes the angle of the other line. I.e. $\varphi$ changes, even though $\theta$ does not. So $\varphi$ is not a function of $\theta$ alone. But while you claim that only $\theta$ is known, your comments about it indicate that far more is known than you've included here. More details will be needed before this problem can be solved.

Comment: @PaulSinclair well, the red function is known as a function of a variable defined on the tilted line.

Comment: What determines where this construction is taking place?

Comment: @PaulSinclair you can imagine that the tilted line is a real number line, call it $x'$-axis, rotated by $\theta$ from the $x$-axis. If you didn't mean that, than sorry, I don't see what you mean. Where as in probably the complex plane?

Comment: What I mean is this: you appear to be taking a point on the red curve and dropping perpendiculars from it to the $x$-axis and tilted lines, and connecting base points to get the third line. If so, then you are starting with a point on the red curve. That point is also an *input*, not just $\theta$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair yes, look at my comment to TobyMak above where I talk about a solution to $\tan\theta x-\tan?(x-X)=0$. That would be $X$.

Comment: That comment is incomprehensible to anyone but you, because you did not bother to define what you were talking about. You seem to assume that for any symbol you write down we will automatically know what you mean by it. Also note that I was talking about a *point* not a value.

Comment: @PaulSinclair right.. Sorry about that. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your givens, $x', f(x')$ are in the primed coordinate system. It is easier to do this calculation if you consider this "the" coordinate system. So the $x$-axis of the original coordinate system is a line slanting down by an angle of $\theta$. It is the set of points $$\{\vec p\mid \hat n \cdot \vec p = 0\}$$ where $\hat n$ is the unit normal to the line, given by $\hat n = (\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$ (in primed coordinates).

$g(X)$ is the (directed) distance from the point $P = (x', f(x'))$ to this down-slanting line, which is given by $P\cdot \hat n$. The projection $Q$ of $P$ onto the line is then $P - (P\cdot \hat n)\hat n$. $X$ is the distance from $Q$ to the origin$. Putting it all together:

$$\hat n = (\sin \theta, \cos \theta)\\P = (x', f(x'))\\g(X) = P \cdot \hat n = x'\sin\theta + f(x')\cos \theta\\Q = \big(x' - (x'\sin\theta + f(x')\cos \theta)\sin \theta, f(x') - (x'\sin\theta + f(x')\cos \theta)\cos\theta\big)\\=(x'\cos\theta - f(x')\sin\theta)\big(\cos\theta, \sin\theta\big)\\X = x'\cos\theta - f(x')\sin\theta$$

In short:
$$X = x'\cos\theta - f(x')\sin\theta\\g(X) = x'\sin\theta + f(x')\cos \theta$$

Comment: Hello Paul, thank you for your answer! Notice that we could've also done the usual transformation $\hat x'\mapsto \cos\theta\hat x+\sin\theta\hat y$, $\hat y'\mapsto -\sin\theta\hat x+\cos\theta\hat y$, and replaced them in $x\hat x'+f(x)\hat y'$. I have already tried this, though, but couldn't eliminate $x$, or $x'$ in your notation.

Comment: for my ellipse function that is.

Comment: I don't know why you accepted my answer if it is not what you are after. It's alright to just say that I misinterpreted your question. So you are wanting to express $g(x)$ as a function of $x$ directly? The big problem here is that what is a function graph in one coordinate system may not be a function graph in the other coordinate system. This implies there cannot be a simple algebraic solution that works for generic $f$.